# Is it true that $\forall a,b\in \mathbb{Q}\smallsetminus \{ 0 \}\exists c,d\in \mathbb{N}:(ac+b)^{2}+(a+db)^{2}\in \mathbb{N}$?

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification

My reasoning went like this:

$$(ac+b)^{2}+(a+db)^{2}=(\frac{a_1c}{a_2}+\frac{b_1}{b_2})^{2}+(\frac{a_1}{a_2}+\frac{b_1d}{d_2})^{2},a_1,a_2,b_1,b_2\in \mathbb{Z}.$$

That is equivalent to:
$$\frac{(a_1c)^{2}+a_1^{2}}{a_2^{2}}+\frac{2a_1b_1(c+d)}{a_2b_2}+\frac{b_1^{2}+(b_1d)^{2}}{b_2^{2}}=\frac{b_2^{2}a_1^{2}(c^{2}+1)+2a_1b_1a_2b_2(c+d)+a_2^{2}b_1^{2}
(d^{2}+1)}{a_2^{2}b_2^{2}}.$$

That expression is a natural number if the numerator contains a factor of $a_2^{2}b_2^{2}$ ,which happens if $a_2^{2}=c^{2}+1 \wedge a_2b_2=c+d\wedge b_2^{2}=d^{2}+1$.

As far as I can see that means that it is not possible to construct such $c,d\in \mathbb{N}$ for every $a_2,b_2$. Is this correct? Any help and correct/alternative solutions would be appreciated.

Comment: If you think it is not possible, then give an explicit counterexample $(a,b)$.

Comment: Try $a=1/7$, $b=1$.

Comment: Or $a=2,b=1/2$ which gives $4c^2+2c+2d+4+\frac{d^2+1}{4}$, which cannot be integer since $d^2\not\equiv -1 \mod 4$.